# RichEdit needs two clicks to change cursor (caret) position when changing the active form (Delphi)

Tags: delphi, caret, richedit

Here's the setting (I'm using Delphi 7, not sure if this will happen in later/earlier versions):

Create a new project with two forms.
Put a `TMemo`, a `TRichEdit` and a `TButton` on the first form.
Set the `Lines` properties of both the `TMemo` and the `TRichEdit` to `123456`.
In the `TButton`'s `OnClick` event handler put `Form2.Show;`

Run the application, click the button and the empty `Form2` will show and get focus.
Now click in the middle of the text "123456" of the `TMemo` in `Form1` - the focus will change back to `Form1` and the cursor (caret) will be in the middle of the text "123456" where you clicked as expected.
Click on `Form2` again to give it focus again.
Now click in the middle of the text "123456" of the `TRichEdit` in `Form1` - the focus will change back to `Form1`, but the cursor (caret) won't be in the middle of the text "123456" where you clicked, but on the second empty line of the `RichEdit` (or wherever it was previously).
If you click a second time in the same place in the middle of the text "123456" of the `TRichEdit`, the cursor (caret) will now be moved there as expected.

So the `TRichEdit` control gets focus, but the cursor (caret) isn't moved as expected.

Note: This only happens when changing the focus from one form to another. Changing the focus from one control to a TRichEdit control in the same form doesn't exhibit this problematic behavior.

My question: How to avoid the need for this second click inside a `TRichEdit` and have the control behave like the `TMemo` in this regard.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Most likely this is nothing to do with Delphi and is just the standard behaviour of these Windows controls.

Comment: Also happens when switching focus from another application.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan yes, that's what I thought too, as the RichEdit controls are Windows controls, not Delphi controls. It's still a problematic confusing behavior that makes no sense and needs a solution.

Comment: Why does it need a solution?

Comment: Refer users to wordpad, if anyone complains.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan well, **I** need a solution. I've replaced a TMemo with a TRichEdit control in an app and people complain about this behavior. I also find it confusing and incorrect myself.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz I want to fix the issue, not point out other applications that have it.

Comment: The solution is simple enough. The user clicks again.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan that is actually the problem :) You can't deny it would be better if the user didn't have to click twice. It _is_ confusing.

Comment: I agree. But it's not easy to achieve. And the user mostly won't notice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can derive a new control, or subclass the richedit in any way you like, to intervene with the activation mechanism. Below sample interposer class sets the focus to the control before the mouse down message is posted when it is about to be activated by the left button of the mouse if the control is not already focused:

```
type
  TRichEdit = class(comctrls.TRichEdit)
  protected
    procedure WMMouseActivate(var Message: TWMMouseActivate);
      message WM_MOUSEACTIVATE;
  end;

procedure TRichEdit.WMMouseActivate(var Message: TWMMouseActivate);
begin
  if (GetFocus <> Handle) and (Message.MouseMsg = WM_LBUTTONDOWN) then
    SetFocus;
  inherited;
end;
```